# Extract Hashtags from String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Let's say I have a paragraph with some hashtags and I want to copy those out and display them separately. Here's some dummy Text:

> Visualize how you can e-enable #vertical #architectures? Whenever you
>   can, disintermediate vertical #convergence? #Visualize how you can
>   e-enable #vertical architectures? Whenever you can, disintermediate
>   vertical #convergence?

I'd like to present the hashtags: #convergence, #Visualize, #vertical on my template.

Comment: are you looking for just displaying them or storing them somewhere as well? the answer would differ based on your use.

Comment: please provide some attempt or code.

Comment: if you're looking on storing it, you'd require a ruby gem to do the processing on the server side. http://rubular.com/ this is a good one to use. If you're just displaying it on the browser, you can use the javascript's native regular expression syntax or use rubular in your embedded ruby htmls. Regular Expressions would be your way to go ahead though!

Comment: Not looking to store it, just display it. Answers below did the trick.

Comment: @Monk_Code You're right. I blame fatigue. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
str = "Visualize how you can e-enable #vertical #architectures?..."
str.scan(/#\w+/).flatten #=> ["#vertical", "#architectures", "#convergence",...]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using regex,

```
input = 'Visualize how you can e-enable #vertical #architectures? Whenever you can, disintermediate vertical #convergence? #Visualize how you can e-enable #vertical architectures? Whenever you can, disintermediate vertical #convergence?'
input.scan(/#(\w+)/)
```

will get you

```
[["vertical"], ["architectures"], ["convergence"], ["Visualize"], ["vertical"], ["convergence"]]
```